# In Jssor nested slider, can you display text outside(below) of slider based on thumbnail selection

Tags: jssor

I am trying to display text below the images based on the image group (thumbnail) selected.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Given html content of thumbnail is as follows, you can change and edit the content.

```
<div u="thumb">
    <img src="../img/nested-thumb/motor.jpg" />
    <div class="title_back"></div>
    <div class="title">
        Motor
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you can edit css for the thumbnail.

Comment: I understand that I can modify that, but I'm trying to add text outside of the thumbnail.  Would display as slider images, then thumbnail text below, as it does now, then outside of the thumbnail image display with text, a description of the image category being displayed.  This text would change based on thumbnail selected.  Hope this examples a little better.  Thanks!